# Bootstrap navbar layout and background picture too small

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a Bootstrap 5 web page according to a supplied design. I am facing few issues.

This is the design:

[image]

My current progress:

[image]

The first issue is the navbar. I have troubles to position the elements at the same distance from the sides as it was designed. The second issue is that when I open the menu, the menu is moved to top and left.

[image]

The third issue is the size of the hero section. I want it to be higher to show the complete image.

The last issue is the width of the headings. I would like to wrap it on too big displays.

Source code snippets:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    .bg-image {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: 50%;
      background-image: url('../assets/images/bg/hero-section-image-bg.jpg');
    }
    .navbar {
      height: 6rem;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
  <div class="bg-image" style="">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-white m-auto" href="#"><h2>Lelisoft</h2></a>
        <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-white" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              <img src="../assets/images/icons/us-flag.svg" alt="english" width="32">
              English
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a class="dropdown-item text-white" href="#">
                  <img src="../assets/images/icons/cz-flag.svg" alt="cesky" width="32">
                  Cesky
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div style="padding: 200px 0 200px;">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="text-white" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);">
          <h1 class="mb-3">Boost Efficiency and Productivity: Modernize Your Legacy Apps Today!</h1>
          <h2 class="mb-3">Don't let your legacy applications slow down your business.</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

I doubt I started correctly. I am not proficient with CSS so I seek for an advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the improved code with explanation at the end.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='end'>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    .bg-image {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center 0%;
      background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1600210491369-e753d80a41f3?crop=entropy&cs=srgb&fm=jpg&ixid=M3wzMjM4NDZ8MHwxfHJhbmRvbXx8fHx8fHx8fDE2ODczNDI0OTN8&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&q=85');
      height: 760px;
    }
    .navbar {
      height: 6rem;
    }
    .top-nav{
      padding: 0px 70px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
  <div class="bg-image">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid border border-danger top-nav">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-dark" href="#"><h2>Lelisoft</h2></a>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            English
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cesky</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div style="padding: 200px 0 200px;">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="text-white" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);">
          <h1 class="mb-3">Boost Efficiency and Productivity: Modernize Your Legacy Apps Today!</h1>
          <h2 class="mb-3">Don't let your legacy applications slow down your business.</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Solutions to your problems:

1. You have used margin auto class of bootstrap(m-auto) for anchor tag(the link) as
   well as on the ul element in the nav bar. This causes it to apply a lot of margin
   and causes to have a lot of space from the sides. I have made a new css class:
   "nav-top" and applied custom padding of 70 px on the left and right side of the
   parent container of anchor tag and ul item, you may change the amount of padding
   according to your need.
2. Solved the menu problem by using a dropdown component. If you have any difficulty related to components, go to Bootstrap website and under "Components" you can see how different elements are implemented. Copy the code and make changes according to your requirements.
3. For the hero, I have given the hero div a height of 570px(you may change the height according to your needs) and I have positioned the background image in the following way:

   background-position: center 0%;

   This centers the image horizontally and moves the image up to the top. As you
   increase the 0% value to 10% or 40%, the image will move down respectively(If 0%
   then image is moved top, if 100%, image is moved to the bottom). You
   may move the image up and down vertically according to your need.
4. For the heading, limit the width of the outer div to say maybe 70% or 80%. Such as:

   div{
   width: 80%;
   }

Comment: Thanks. I created a codepan: https://codepen.io/literakl/pen/XWyjdMo.  I still need to upload the images (set up a webserver, waiting for DNS refresh). It shows the menu problem anyway.

Comment: Ad headings - I think I need to set a DIV width to 80 rem or so, as the headings are too long and hard to read.

Comment: Pictures are uploaded at codepen, but it does not show them. Weird.

Comment: Yes you may limit the div size so that the headings do not take up the whole screen and I would like to suggest to use percentage(for example 70%) and not rem.

Comment: Can you see the cause of this menu glitches?

Comment: Yes. I realize the menu causes it to move up